# check input against laravel5.1 generated password (bcrypt / hash / application key)

Tags: php, hash, laravel-5.1, bcrypt

I'm using laravel5.1 in my main application, where users can register account etc. Now I need to authenticate users input (username and password) on a second server against the userdata I stored on my database server created by laravel. Checking username is easy, but is there an PHP function for bcrypt where I can put my laravel application token into, so I can check, if a password, entered by a user is the same password the user used to register through laravel?

Comment: One option is to make your main application also an OAuth2 server and your other app can authenticate against it: https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel

Comment: laravel internally uses [bcrypt with 10 rounds](https://github.com/illuminate/hashing/blob/master/BcryptHasher.php#L30), it done with [`password_hash` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) if your second application is capable to access laravel's database (main application) directly you could use `password_hash` for authentication. however @JeremyHarris pointed that you could use OAuth-style authentication, this used if your second application can't access laravel's database directly. design choice is up to you, there are some benefit and drawbacks.